# Find function to relate two lists of values

Tags: functions, function-construction, fitting

I know Mathematica has the FindFit function to determine the parameters of a known function that fits a sequence of points, but what if you do not know the relationship (linear, log, quadratic, etc)?

For example, if I have two lists of values:

```
x={1, 3, 5, 11}
y={1, 9, 25, 121}
```

Is there a way Mathematica can automatically figure out that y=x^2 ?

Comment: `x = Table[2 i + 1, {i, 10}]; y = x^2; 
FindSequenceFunction[Transpose[{x, y}], n] // Simplify`

Comment: But `FindSequenceFunction[ ]`  doesn't guess very well ...

Answer (score 6):

`FindFormuala` is EXPERIMENTAL and new in v10.2

```
Clear[x, y];

xData = {1, 3, 5, 11};
yData = {1, 9, 25, 121};

y[x_] = FindFormula[Transpose[{xData, yData}], x]

(*  x^2  *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
data = Transpose[{x, y}];
FindFormula[data, z]
```